# Re-Direct ALL Users to the Home Page IF not logged in

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I just read the codex on `wp_redirect();` and found an example that I modified. Problem is, all I get is an error in my browser saying "The page isn’t redirecting properly".

I need all users, unless logged in, to be re-directed to the home page (`home_url()`).

Can someone please help me?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'not_logged_in_redirect_home' );
add_action( 'do_feed', 'not_logged_in_redirect_home' );
function not_logged_in_redirect_home() {

        if ( is_home() ) return;

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_home() ) return;

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && !is_home() ) {
    
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
    
            exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if you're already on the homepage?

Comment: Then do nothing. Guess I should have added a `return` argument for `if ( is_home() ) return;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'not_logged_in_redirect_home' );
add_action( 'do_feed', 'not_logged_in_redirect_home' );
function not_logged_in_redirect_home(){

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ){

        return false;

    }

    if ( 
        ! is_home() // use this option if you show blogs posts on the home page
        // ! is_front_page() // use this if you show a static page
    ){

        wp_redirect( home_url() );

        exit;
    }
}
```

Check the documentation on is_home() - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

Since WordPress 2.1, when the static front page functionality was introduced, the blog posts index and site front page have been treated as two different query contexts, with is_home() applying to the blog posts index, and is_front_page() applying to the site front page

So, you might need to use is_front_page() - depending on your setup.

Comment: Same problem with your code.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Made a small change, try again.

Comment: No, still the same. I added `;` after false and still the same problem.

Comment: Hmm.. code looks good, perhaps try in an incognito or drop your cache and try again.. but perhaps is_home() is not returning true for your home_url..? is this set in the admin/settings/reading?

Comment: You're right. It was a mistake between home and front page. Thanks for reminding me.